# Search if a cell contains different types of strings and output a string according to that

Tags: google-sheets

I use a google form to get responses from students, and the form is linked to my spreadsheet. I have another tab where I try to process all the data, and the first column is about the students' class and what their major is. So some of them wrote M1, M2 or Master 1. Some younger students wrote Licence 1, or L1, L2 (For the ones doing their bachelor, I'm in France)

So what I want to do is to get the strings in a specific cell, check if they are either "M1", "M2", "Master", "Licence" or whatever, and output a string "Master" or "Licence" (For Bachelor)

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your reply !
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSyuFYbCkRQ5nq9ntxyk11-I94SYeT0Xrr9rt9uXDv0eKGkJyIY_TSk-6AXh7vqydXVH2XzNsPoY-yG/pubhtml)

Comment: you want  L3 too?

Comment: Yes please, I need all the Ms and Ls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE({A:A,PROPER(B:B)},
 "M1|M2|Master 1", "Master"), 
 "L1|L2|L3", "Licence")),
 "where Col2 contains 'Master'
     or Col2 contains 'Licence'")
```

[image: 0]

French syntax:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE({A:A\PROPER(B:B)};
 "M1|M2|Master 1|Master 2"; "Master"); 
 "L1|L2|L3|Licence 1|Licence 2|Licence 3"; "Licence"));
 "where Col2 contains 'Master'
     or Col2 contains 'Licence'")
```

Comment: Thank you so much !
And if I want to get the cells from another sheet ? 
Where should I add the 'Reference'! ?

Comment: `{A:A\PROPER(B:B)\'Reference'!C:C}`